# std::bind won't accept an std::cref of a bind-placeholder - why?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, methods, bind

I try to pass a method as a parameter function, which itself takes a parameter, by using std::cref, but somehow I cannot get it right. What is wrong?

```
struct node 
{
    void get(int &i){ 
        i = x; 
    }

    int x, z;
    void foo(std::function<void(int&)>t){ 
        t(z); 
    }

    void bar(){
        x = 7;
        z = 10;
        foo(std::bind(&node::get, this, std::cref(_1)));

        cout<< "z:" << z << std::endl; //Here is expected that z is changed to 7
    }
};
```

Comment: Lambdas mean there's no real reason to ever need to use `std::bind()` in new code...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat notes that the problem is the use of `std::cref`; you can just use `_1` apparently. But I'll let HolyBlackCat do the honors of writing the answer themselves.

Comment: `std::cref` creates a reference to a `const T`, but `get()` takes a reference to a non-const `int`, so why would you expect this kind of binding to ever compile, even if it were legal to wrap the `_1` placeholder like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::bind` can only process placeholders directly as parameters: `std::bind(…, _1, …)`.

`std::cref(_1)` wraps the placeholder in a `std::reference_wrapper`. `bind` doesn't recognize it as a placeholder anymore, and tries to pass it directly to the bound function, as it would do with any other non-placeholder parameter.

To work around this and other limitations of `bind`, use a lambda:

```cpp
foo([this](int &x){return get(std::ref(x));});
```

I've replaced `cref` with `ref` here, because `get()` expects a non-const reference. You can't use `cref` here, with or without the lambda. (Note that `std::ref(x)` is equivalent to `x` here, and is used instead of `x` for demonstration purposes only.)

Comment: You don't need the `std::ref` in the lambda since `x` is already a reference and `get()` takes a reference: `foo([this](int &x){return get(x);});`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah. I've used it to demonstrate that it *can* be used with a lambda (unlike with `bind`).